# Dos REN command syntax

Tags: rename, dos

Standard ren command is ok, but I have a number of files that I need to delete some information in the middle.
ex: (movie name).Title1.mp4
I need to remove .Title1

I tried ren *.Title1.* *.* ,
        ren *.*.* *.* ,
        ren *.*.* *.mp4 ,
and some other variations and none worked. I think its an easy fix but I haven't had any luck with it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This bat file does rename all files which contain ".Title1". e.g.test.Title1.txt -> test.txt

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /B /O *Title1*') DO (
  SET title_orig=%%G
  ren %%G %title_orig:.Title1=%
)
```